# Stream file as RTSP using VLC

Tags: streaming, vlc

I need to create a server that can stream an mp3 file to another device.  I am planning on using VLC.  I looked at the VLC documentation and am confused about the way forward to do this.  I found this link, http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch07.html which tells how to stream a file to a device.  However, what I want to do is create a server that is just streaming audio and will allow other clients to connect to it and start playing what is streamed.  How can this be done with VLC?

Comment: Why VLC instead of icecast, which was designed from the start to be a media streaming contraption?

Comment: i need to transcode stuff also as well as extract audio from video files...

Comment: btw the link is 404 now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are OK with using just an RTP stream then try https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New. This is the absolute simplest method, and I used it very recently.

If you would like to setup a full-fledged on-demand RTSP server then use this: http://juliensimon.blogspot.com/2008/12/howto-setting-up-vod-server-with-vlc.html  .

Answer (score -1):

Open Broadcaster Software supports RTSP https://obsproject.com

Comment: It only supports RTSP as a source for input. You cannot create an RTSP stream from OBS.

Comment: @Chris I think it can now with an RTSP Plugin: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-rtspserver.1037/